# Grep files with regex

Tags: grep

I have a file with a bunch of log lines.

I want to return files that contain the word 'fail' in it, but that don't contain the pattern:

```
Failed any test here _fr in Pro-any text here
```

So if it contains:
_fr in Pro-

Then ignore the line even if it has the word fail in it.

Comment: Yuo might be interested in [Logparser (Microsoft's one) or similar for Unix?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/185813/1115360).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat >test.log
keep fail
omit fail  _fr in Pro-
```

To find all the lines that match your criteria:

```
$ awk '/[fF]ail/ && ! /_fr in Pro-/' test.log
keep fail
```

To print just the names of files that have lines matching your criteria:

```
$ awk '/[fF]ail/ && ! /_fr in Pro-/ {print FILENAME; exit}' *.log
test.log
```

**How it works:**

Awk implicitly reads through a file line-by-line.  The condition `/[fF]ail/ && ! /_fr in Pro-/` matches any line that contains `Fail` or `fail` but does not contain `_fr in Pro-`.  In awk `&&` means logical-and and `!` means logical-not.

#### Rejecting both `_fr in Pro-` and `_en in Pro-`

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat test.log
keep fail
omit fail  _fr in Pro-
omit fail  _en in Pro-
```

To reject both forms:

```
$ awk '/[fF]ail/ && ! /_(fr|en) in Pro-/' test.log
keep fail
```

Comment: How could _fr or _en?   I tried _[fr|en] but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @coolbreeze `[fr|en]` matches any of the characters `f`, `r`, `|`, `e`, or `n`.  The form for logical-or is `(fr|en)`.  See updated answer for more.